# Method is failing in Production Only : Field is not writeable: CaseShare.CaseId

Tags: deployment

I am trying to Deploy below code in production but getting errors as

Errors :

> Field is not writeable: CaseShare.CaseId
>
> Field is not writeable: CaseShare.UserOrGroupId

Code:

```
 public void updateOwnerAndShareCase(){
        try{
            System.debug('Inside class method');
            System.debug('recordId**'+CaseRecordId);
            List<Case> caseList=[SELECT Id,CaseNumber,OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id=:CaseRecordId LIMIT 1];
            if(caseList.size()>0){
                System.debug('caseList**'+caseList[0]);
                List<User> userList=[SELECT Id, UserName FROM User WHERE Name='XXXX' LIMIT 1];
                caseList[0].OwnerId=userList[0].Id;
                update caseList;
                // Create new sharing object for the custom object Job.
                CaseShare objCaseShare  = new CaseShare();
                objCaseShare.CaseId = caseList[0].Id;
                objCaseShare.UserOrGroupId = UserInfo.getUserId();
                objCaseShare.CaseAccessLevel = 'Read';
                objCaseShare.RowCause = Schema.CaseShare.RowCause.Manual;
                insert objCaseShare;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Error Message** '+e.getMessage() + ' Error Line** '+e.getLineNumber());
        }
    }
```

Tried to recompile classes, but no luck! TIA!

Comment: Whats the org wide default for case object?. It shouldnt be public read write

Comment: @RedDevil its `Public Read/Write/Transfer`

Comment: Why would you create case share for public read/write? its anyways visible to everyone. Only for private and public read only we create case share records to open up additional access

Comment: @RedDevil Oops, My Bad !! That make sense, Got It, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, In my sandbox **OWD** for case was **Private** that's why the code was working fine in Sandbox, but in Production it was **Public** and it doesn't allow to insert sharing record when its public(there may be exceptions), so commented the code for sharing and I was able to deploy the changes.